# printing a 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays

The program I need to write is a square 2d array made of numbers, like this

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

or this

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

The program reads the number "d" (side of the square 2d array- above are examples of d=3 and d=5), number "n" (how many inputs there will be next) and these n inputs (eg. if n=3, the program should let me insert three numbers, like from the first example, let's say I'd choose 1 and 4 and 3. So the input looks like:

```
3
3
1 4 2
```

Then, it needs to calculate the distance between the first and second, second and third input and sum them up. That sum is then the output. Here is the program

```
if(b==2) {
                int d=sc.nextInt();
                int n=sc.nextInt();



                int[][] array=new int[d][d]; //length and heigth of array

                int c=0;
                int manhattanDistanceSum=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n;  i ++){ //for inserting values
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j ++){

                        if (i < n){
                            i++;

                            array[i][j] = sc.nextInt();

                        } 
                        else {
                            break;        
                        }



                        for( i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
                            for( j=0;j<array[0].length;j++) {
                                array[i][j]=c; //actual locations of numbers
                                               //numbers in array

                                c++;

                                if(manhattanDistanceSum != 0) {
                                        int dx= c / d;
                                        int dy= c % d;


                                        c=Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy);
                                        manhattanDistanceSum+=c;

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
                                System.out.println();
                    }
                }


                System.out.println(manhattanDistanceSum);

            }

    }
}
```

*the b doesn't matter, it just means this is going to be a square array, so ignore it. It has nothing to do with this.
This is all I got, and need help with anything that is wrong in my code.
Thankyou

Comment: `System.out.println` should be outside the second `for` loop?

Comment: Um, nope. It says sth like : "Exception in thread main..."

Comment: *"sth like"* - Post the actual exception, don't give vague descriptions. And point out to which line of the code it refers

Comment: Masa Egart, do you understand that by "outside the second for loop", Unholy Sheep means "after the `}` character that closes the  inner loop"?  They have given you correct advice.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at Name.main(Name.java 66)

Comment: Well, I did exactly that and this above(My last comment) is the output

Comment: An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` cannot be related to moving a call to `System.out.println()`, you must have changed something else as well

Comment: You'd get better help if you showed us the entire program.  There are at least 60 lines that you haven't reproduced here.

Comment: There's so much more to it, this is just one of the problems I'm facing. Let me edit the original question.

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's easier to see everything now.

Comment: I'm still missing the edited code that causes your runtime exception. My suggestion should work.

Comment: It's already edited, the system.out.println(array[i][j]) is out of both for loops if you can see.

Comment: Why did you move `System.out.print(array[i][j]);` out of the inner loop?? That is not what I suggested you do

Answer (score 0):

I've just cobbled together this example and tested that it works with positive and negative numbers. It might not do exactly what you want (for example, is the data in your array organised row-by-column or column-by-row) and it might not exactly format the output the way you want, but it should show you how to iterate through the array and analyse and then extract the data to produce a `String` which can be printed out.

Be sure to conduct your own testing (create unit tests for all cases which your application will need) as I have thrown this together in a few minutes in the hope that it would get you started. It should not be considered a finished product by any means.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] data = {{0, -10734, 2}, {3, 437, 5}, {6, 733838, 8}};
    System.out.println("Table:\n" + formatAsTable(data));
}

public static String formatAsTable(int[][] squareNumericArray) {
    int cellSpacing = 2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int squareSide = squareNumericArray.length;
    int cellSize = findLargestNumericString(squareNumericArray)
            + cellSpacing;
    for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < squareSide; ++firstIndex) {
        if (squareNumericArray[firstIndex].length != squareSide) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Array must have same size in both dimensions.");
        }
        for (int secondIndex = 0; secondIndex < squareSide; ++secondIndex) {
            sb.append(String.format("%-" + cellSize + "d",
                    squareNumericArray[firstIndex][secondIndex]));
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static int findLargestNumericString(int[][] squareNumericArray) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < squareNumericArray.length;
            ++firstIndex) {
        for (int secondIndex = 0; secondIndex
                < squareNumericArray[firstIndex].length; ++secondIndex) {
            String numberAsString = Integer.toString(
                    squareNumericArray[firstIndex][secondIndex]);
            if (numberAsString.length() > maxLength) {
                maxLength = numberAsString.length();
            }
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

This code will output the following to the console:

```
Table:
0       -10734  6       
3       437     5       
6       733838  19
```